# What edible mushrooms can be grown in full sun?

Tags: mushrooms

I would like to grow some mushrooms in my vegetable garden which is in full sun.  Are there any varieties of edible mushrooms that like direct sun?

Comment: None that are grown commercially that I am aware of. There are some that pop up in lawns, shaggy mane and other inky caps... Some inky caps are mildly poisonous if consumed with alcohol... So be advised that you should always really do your research... The downside is that when you are done with your research, your once tasty shaggy mane has self digested to a pile of black goo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only one I know of is the Stropharia aka wine cap mushroom below is text taken from [here](http://www.oregonlive.com/hg/index.ssf/2012/04/vern_nelson_grow_giant_mushroo.html) on planting them

Stropharia always produced best in sun or broken shade with well-drained, moist soil. Mushroom mycelium needs to be mixed with fresh hardwood chips or sawdust. Do not use chips or sawdust from pine, cedar, redwood, eucalyptus, juniper or other fragrant woods. Fresh straw, NOT hay, can also be used, though it doesn't last as long as wood chips.

The chip/mycelium mix can be used as a mulch in garden beds or sprinkled down the center of caneberry rows. Stropharia always flourished among my raspberries; the combination of berries and mushrooms made good use of space. You can also grow mushrooms between corn rows or scattered among bok choy, kale, lettuces or other salad greens. Keep the patch watered but not wet.

Comment: What kind of Mushrooms do you grow under your raspberries? What kind of mulch do you use for those mushrooms?