# What type of edible mushrooms can I easily inoculate in logs and grow in USDA zone 4a for full sun?

Tags: sunlight, mushrooms, permaculture, back-to-eden

I'm currently building a home fungal/crop garden, and am wondering what types of mushrooms can inoculate fresh cut oak logs with that will grow in full sun next to tall grass on one side, and a wood chip bed on the other side. It will be cooking at about 160 all winter long (2'-3' X 20' X 100' so mycelium will be "running").

Comment: You really need to give the dimensions of the oak branches. If they're logs you might be waiting a few decades for them to fruit.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with growing mushrooms at all, but in the past I have seen my father growing shiitake on logs in his garden. Shiitake can be grown on live oak (*Quercus virginiana*) in USDA zones 3 to 9 (see [here](https://homeguides.sfgate.com/reproduction-shiitake-mushrooms-91694.html) for more info).

Comment: full sun would be 90-100% sun

Comment: Maybe this previous [post](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4455/what-edible-mushrooms-can-be-grown-in-full-sun) will help.

Comment: any other ones in full sun?

Comment: I don't know if it was edible, but I saw some kind of mushroom (a cluster of them of good size) growing in extremely dry bare soil that had received no water for months, as far as I'm aware (no rain), which soil was in full, strong sun. I didn't know that was possible, but yeah, some fungi can do it!